# Angular how to correctly destroy directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a 'regionMap' directive that includes methods for rendering and destroying the map. The map is rendered inside of a modal and upon clicking the modal close button the 'regionMap' destroy method is called, which should remove the element and scope from the page. However, when returning to the modal page, that includes the 'region-map' element, the previous 'region-map' element is not removed,  resulting in multiple maps being displayed. What is the correct way to remove the regionMap directive from the page when the modal is closed?

// directive

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular.module('homeModule')
.directive('regionMap', regionMap);

function regionMap() {

    var directive = { 
            restrict: 'E',
        template: '',
        replace: true,
        link: link,
        scope: {
            regionItem: '=',
            accessor: '='
        }
    }

    return directive;

    function link(scope, el, attrs, controller) {
        if (scope.accessor) {
            scope.accessor.renderMap = function(selectedRegion) {
                var paper = Raphael(el[0], 665, 245);
                paper.setViewBox(0, 0, 1100, 350, false);
                paper.setStart();
                for (var country in worldmap.shapes) {
                    paper.path(worldmap.shapes[country]).attr({
                      "font-size": 12,
                      "font-weight": "bold",
                      title: worldmap.names[country],
                      stroke: "none",
                      fill: '#EBE9E9',
                      "stroke-opacity": 1
                    }).data({'regionId': country});
                }

                paper.forEach(function(el) {
                    if (el.data('regionId') != selectedRegion.name) {
                      el.stop().attr({fill: '#ebe9e9'});
                    } else {
                      el.stop().attr({fill: '#06767e'});
                    }
                });
            }
            scope.accessor.destroyMap = function() {
                scope.$destroy();
                el.remove();
            }
        }
    }
 }


})();
```

// controller template:

```
<region-map accessor="modalvm.accessor" region-item="modalvm.sregion"></region-map>
```

// controller:

```
vm.accessor = {};

...

function showMap() {

$rootScope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function(event) {
    if (vm.accessor.renderMap) {
        vm.accessor.renderMap(vm.sregion);
    }
});

function closeMap() {
    if (vm.accessor.destroyMap) {
        vm.accessor.destroyMap();
    }
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
}
```

Comment: Can you please say how you figured out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to loading a template with a directive inside of it. Fixed it by adding a var to check if the map has previously been rendered:

```
vm.accessor.mapRendered = false;
$rootScope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function(event) {
  if (vm.accessor.renderMap && !vm.accessor.mapRendered) {
    vm.accessor.renderMap(vm.selectedRegions);
    vm.accessor.mapRendered = true;
  }
});
```